# Javascript: undefined as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, undefined

On this [page](https://carldanley.com/js-observer-pattern/), it shows some example code, containing the following line:

```
var Subject = ( function( window, undefined ) {
```

What is the `undefined` as a function parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is used to prevent from overriding the value of `undefined` in non-strict mode.

In non-strict mode, the value of `undefined` can be override by assigning other value to it.

```
undefined = true; // Or any other value
```

So, using the value of `undefined` will not work as expected.

In strict-mode, `undefined` is read-only and assigning value to it will throw error.

In the code, the value to the last parameter is not passed, so it'll be implicitly passed as `undefined`.

```
var Subject = ( function( window, undefined ) {

}(window)); // <-- No parameter is passed for the last value
```

Answer (score 3):

That is done to make sure that undefined always is undefined. In JavaScript, since undefined isn't a reserved word but a regular variable, this would be allowed for instance:

```
 undefined = 2; // Assign a different value to undefined
 if (undefined == 2)  // Now this statement would be true
```

So in your case

```
var Subject = ( function( window, undefined ) {
```

They pass in window and use it , but then they don't pass a second value to the undefined parameter, thus undefined will be undefined.

Comment: Huh.  I'm guessing this is done as a matter of principle, since it's not actually used.  But that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: and this happens in non-strict mode only.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used to be able to redefine the value of `undefined`, but not anymore. Undefined is a special type that has several use cases. If it was redefined to `true`, code like this would break:

```
if(my_var === undefined) { 
     dont_load_missiles());
} else {
     load_missiles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked a similar question ( [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487492/what-does-undefined-parameter-signify-in-a-function-definition) ) and the community suggested this article.

Following statements in the selected answer ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33383677/1799502) ) theoretically answers the question;

> - This is used to prevent from overriding the value of `undefined` in non-strict mode.
> - In non-strict mode, the value of `undefined` can be override by assigning other value to it.

I believe a practical example might be helpful

```
var undefined = 7;
function printUndefined(undefined) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += undefined + "<br/>";
}

printUndefined(); // Output is undefined
printUndefined(undefined); // Output is 7
printUndefined(10); // Output is 10
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxp68qeL/)

Therefore the only guarantee is that the method caller is in control of the context.